# How can I get my redstone to activate adjacent pistons?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to create my first circuit in minecraft:

- `a` - pressure plate
- `p` - piston
- `d` - dirt
- `-` or `|` - redstone

```
a----dddd
     pppp
```

Pistons are placed over the dirt and there's water under the dirt.

I'm trying this but it doesn't work:

```
a-------
     ddd
     ppp
```

This also doesn't work:

```
----
a ||
  dd
  pp
```

This does work, but only if pistons aren't adjacent

```
a--------
    | | |
    d d d
    p p p
```

Here are two screenshots:

This doesn't work

[image: doesn't work]

This works:

[image]

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say try placing a redstone repeater before every piston if possible. I'm not sure that'll help though.

Comment: Related/Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50459/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-to-wire-a-row-of-pistons

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are actually a large number of different ways you can do this. Perhaps the simplest is using redstone repeaters, like so:

[image]

There's also the design proposed by [StrixVaria](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1719/), which uses elevated redstone:

[image]

But there are even more ways you can do this. Here are a few:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Take your pick!

Comment: +1 cause while it may be possible with out repeaters, you should get used to using them. Almost every compact redstone construction will require them somewhere to make sure the redstone power is flowing in the right direction.

Comment: @James Use repeaters if there is a reason to use repeaters.  Don't use them just for the sake of getting into a good habit.

Comment: @Maxpm Yes I completely agree that good habbits are a thing to be avoided!

Comment: @James In this situation, I'd agree with Maxpm. It seems to be that while repeaters solve the problem, there's no good reason to use them over other methods here.

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
a---+++
    ppp
```

- `a` - pressure plate
- `-` - redstone
- `+` - redstone on a raised block (the block should be at the same level as the piston)
- `p` - piston

[image: A screenshot of the above schematic]
[image: The pistons activated]

Comment: I can't test this right now, since I'm at work. If it doesn't work, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: My testing indicates that it works.

Comment: Sorry i don't know if its my fault but this way like before adiacent wires connect to themselves instead of the block in front of them

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi The wires won't look like they connect to the piston, but they will power the block they lay on, which will in turn power the piston connected to that block.

Comment: i think that with repeater should works, anyway i've posted two screenshots

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi You are not following my schematic. The redstone should go on top of the blocks, and the pistons should be next to the blocks. My schematic is from an overhead position.

Comment: This is the method I use and it's by far the easiest.

Answer (score 2):

In order to power pistons, you either need the redstone line running directly into the piston, run the redstone line on a raised block, or using redstone repeaters. You can also power an adjacent block using a repeater, which can be very useful for certain applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to power a long line of pistons the option with repeaters would be best but you'd have to use additional repeater so the signal doesn't die along the way, and this might be tricky. The attached solution works for me.[image: Powering indefinite rows of pistons]