# Why can't I activate pistons with this layout?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my redstone to activate adjacent pistons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51966/how-can-i-get-my-redstone-to-activate-adjacent-pistons)

I have 4 pistons with the following layout:

```
  T====
   PPPP

 P: piston
 =: restone wire
 T: redstone torch
```

When I put the redstone torch the pistons fail to activate
and remain still. However if do the following:

```
   T
   PPPP
```

The first piston on the left activates as normal.

Shouldn't the redstone wire be enough for activating pistons?

I'm using version 1.2.5 SMP vanilla.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to power a block next to the repeater or create a direct input.

To fix that you either need redstone torches or repeaters:

```
t====
 rrrr
 pppp
```

or

```
t====
 tttt
 pppp
```

or

```
t====
bbbbb <redstone on top of the blocks
 pppp

 t <t=torch and redstone
pb <from the side
```

The exact rules of powering pistons: [MinecraftWiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pistons#Powering_Pistons)

Comment: Ah so the redstore wire brings power only along one direction instead of affecting all adiacent cells, like a torch does

Comment: Yup, redstone wire only powers in the direction it is pointing.