# How do you make a button turn a piston off?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I've made a house, and i want to make it so that i push a secret button, a piston turns **OFF** (because the piston is **ON** to block the passage.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get my redstone to activate adjacent pistons?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51966/how-can-i-get-my-redstone-to-activate-adjacent-pistons)

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this for yourself?  This is literally lesson number one in redstone 101, which says to me that you haven't done any research.  You'll find that people are much more responsive if you put some effort into solving your problem first.

Comment: sorry, i did research. and i couldn't find ANYTHING. and i just signed up into this website too.

Comment: and i already figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Make a NOT Gate. This type of simple redstone logic circuit is essential for creating a circuit that turns something *OFF* when activated, instead of *ON*. Here is a picture:

[image: Torch Inverter NOT Gate]

Just add a button and maybe a repeater for delay, and it will turn off the redstone torch, turning the power OFF.

Comment: +1. Effort like that on a question like this should not go unrewarded.(In addition to making me realize log faces actually make for a NEAT floor texture)